# why TAILQ_FOREACH_SAFE implementation contains ((tvar) = TAILQ_NEXT((var), field), 1)?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

While using queue.h MACRO for safe traversal, I have a doubt

```
#define TAILQ_FOREACH_SAFE(var, head, field, tvar)       \
    for ((var) = TAILQ_FIRST((head));                    \
        (var) && ((tvar) = TAILQ_NEXT((var), field), 1); \
        (var) = (tvar))
```

Why tailing 1 is added in `((tvar) = TAILQ_NEXT((var), field), 1)` statement ?

Comment: Is this using the BSD `sys/queue.h` header?

Answer (score 2):

```
((tvar) = TAILQ_NEXT((var), field), 1);
```

This uses the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator). The expression on the left side of the comma is evaluated and its result discarded, and then the expression on the right side is evaluated and its result returned - the literal 1 in this case, so if `var` is true, the entire `(var) && ((tvar) = TAILQ_NEXT((var), field), 1)` expression is true no matter what `tvar` gets set to, so the `for` loop it's part of continues. It stops when `var` is not true (By being a `NULL` pointer).